# addEventListener click function problem. With each click, the function logs in one more time than before

Tags: javascript, function, scope, click, increment

Here's the code:

```
let chance20 = 60;

function lift20kg() {
   pickNumber();
   button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chance20 +=5;
      commentary.textContent = `Good lift! Now you got ${chance20}% chance to lift 20kg`;
      liftCommentary.textContent = 'Good Lift!';
      
      console.log(chance20);
   }))
```

So the problem is, the first click returns 65 - its ok. Next click return 70 and 75, so log in 2 times. Then return 80, 85 and 90, so one click log 3 numbers. And go on...

My goal is of course increasing the number by 5 with each click (increasing the chance to lift more weight by 5%).

I suppose it's about scoping, but I don't know enough to figure it out.

I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: You're not showing how you invoke `lift20kg()` but by the explanation it seems you're doing it on a button click or another interaction. Each time this interaction is performed, you're adding a new event listener to button1, hence the number of executions.

Comment: Yeah, 30 second after post it, I moved inside function out of lift20kg() function and it works for now. Thank you anyway for quick answer <3

Answer (score 0):

As konstantin mentions, its difficult to know properly what youre doing without more code. But as a stab in the dark, you will want to either remove the lift20kg function altogether and just have the event listener function, OR  remove the event listener function. I've included an example of both below.

This first example removes the event listener. You may want this because your button1 html tag includes onClick="lift20kg()", in which case you dont need the event listener at all.

```
var chance20 = 60;
function lift20kg() {
  pickNumber();
  chance20 +=5;
  commentary.textContent = `Good lift! Now you got ${chance20}% chance to lift 20kg`;
  liftCommentary.textContent = 'Good Lift!';
  
  console.log(chance20);
}
```

OR, if the function lift20kg() isn't actually required, then remove the function altogether and just use the event listener like here:

```
var chance20 = 60;
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pickNumber();
  chance20 +=5;
  commentary.textContent = `Good lift! Now you got ${chance20}% chance to lift 20kg`;
  liftCommentary.textContent = 'Good Lift!';
  
  console.log(chance20);
)}
```

alternatively you can keep both if you really need both by pulling the event listener out of the function and using the event listener to call the function as needed like follows:

```
var chance20 = 60;
function lift20kg() {
  pickNumber();
  chance20 +=5;
  commentary.textContent = `Good lift! Now you got ${chance20}% chance to lift 20kg`;
  liftCommentary.textContent = 'Good Lift!';
  
  console.log(chance20);
}

 button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
   lift20kg();
 })
```

I also changed the 'let chance20' to 'var chance20'.